# GCC shared_ptr and make_shared on map separated var type error

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-ptr

I want to use `std::shared_ptr` and `std::make_shared` and create a map list with separated variable types ... My compiler is GCC and this is my source

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class key_base {

public:

    virtual ~key_base() = default;
    key_base() = default;
    template <typename T> const T & Read();
};

template <typename T>
class key : public key_base {

private:

    T storage_;

public:

    key(const T & __storage) {
        storage_ = __storage;
    }
    const T & Read() { return storage_; }
};

int main() {

    map <int, std::shared_ptr <key_base>> List;

    List[0] = std::make_shared <key<string>>("Hello");
    List[1] = std::make_shared <key<string>>("How old are you?");
    List[2] = std::make_shared <key<int>>(22);


    for (auto thisItem : List) {
        if(thisItem.first == 2)
            cout << thisItem.first << "= (" << thisItem.second->Read<int>() << ")" << endl;
        else
            cout << thisItem.first << "= (" << thisItem.second->Read<string>() << ")" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know one thing about `key_base (Read)` function which need to be virtual and = 0 and also it's must be template (to get the type of var) and it's not possible in GCC (but possible in Microsoft Compiler). What should I do for this too?

Comment: Identifiers with double underscore are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: It looks to me like you just forgot to make your inheritance for `key_base` public. Private inheritance isn't visible from outside the class.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yep. He wants, `class key : public key_base {`. Otherwise, the derivation is an implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you think that dynamic polymorphism will work with templates.

Basically template declaration `template <typename T> const T & Read();` in `base_class` is completely useless.
How do you think compiler deduce what should be done for `Read()` if base class is used? There is no definition of this template and compiler has no idea how to reach subclasses where you are defining this methods.

Your design is wrong and since this is classic [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) we are unable to help you to resolve this properly.

Looks like you should take a look on new template from C++17:
[`std::any`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any)

---

To make it work (I hate the code design), you need add missing template definition after `key` class:

```
template <typename T>
const T & key_base::Read()
{
    if (auto subClassObject = dynamic_cast<key<T> *>(this)) {
        return subClassObject->Read();
    }
    throw domain_error { "Invalid Read use" };
}
```

It works for [Visual Studio](http://rextester.com/CEQFMJ67303).
And it works for [GCC](http://rextester.com/CPNPPL72622).

Comment: if i use microsoft compiler and change this (template <typename T> const T & Read()) to (template <typename T> const T & Read() = 0) my problem solve !!!!!!!

Comment: rely this works on VS? Try my example I wonder what VS will do with that.

Comment: It doesn't compile on VS http://rextester.com/OEX85075 even with your modification.

Comment: please read the question again .. i changed it (a part of question)